# A action is calling when i start my site from VS2013 IDE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

my home controller has many actions and one of action take **datatime as parameter**

```
public ActionResult DateCheck(DateTime? orderdate)
{
return View();
}
```

i have one action link which is pointing **DateCheck** action. here it is

```
@Html.ActionLink("Date route test", "DateCheck", new { orderdate = "12-25-2016" })
```

i have mention a route for **DateCheck** action just **to pass datetime as route data**. here it is

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{orderdate}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DateCheck", orderdate = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

now the problem is when i start my site from VS2013 IDE then **DateCheck** action getting called but it suppose to call when user will click on link. so where is the mistake. help me to fix it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that MVC tries to match routes in the order they are defined.

Also, the `{orderDate}` is defined as `UrlParameter.Optional`.

So when you start your application, the first request for `localhost/Home/Index` is matched by the orderDate route: `{controller}` is `"Home"`, `{action}` is `"Index"` and `{orderdate}` is `null`. The default route is never applied because a matching route has already been found. And the `defaults` of the orderDate route basically say "I don't care which controller and action name you passed to me, I will always redirect you to `Home/DateCheck`".

If the DateCheck action is the only one that accepts an orderDate as route value, change your routing config to reflect this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "orderDate",
    url: "Home/DateCheck/{orderdate}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DateCheck", orderdate = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you do not expect that users will enter this route directly in the browser, you do not need to define an extra route just to increase readability of the URL. Remove the orderDate route, your URL will then look like this: `localhost/Home/DateCheck?orderdate=12-25-2016`.

Comment: i can remove orderDate routing from route.config file but the problem is then orderdate will be passed as query string like `DateCheck?orderdate=12-25-2016` but i want to pass date like `DateCheck/orderdate=12-25-2016`

Comment: Then go with the variant where you have a route that closely matches this request, as shown in my code example. The URL will then be `localhost/Home/DateCheck/12-25-2016`.